# Type mismatch expecting NotInferedR

Tags: scala, slick

I'm attempting to get a basic working Slick proof working but am getting a Type Mismatch error from this line:

```
def * : MappedProjection[Nothing, (Option[Int], String)] = (id.?, name) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
```

Specifically, the `User.tupled` and `User.unapply` have the following errors, respectively:

```
Type mismatch, expected: Option[(Option[Int], String)] => NotInferedR, actual: Option[(Option[Int], String)] => User
```

and

```
Type mismatch, expected: NotInferedR => Option[(Option[Int], String)], actual: User => option[(Option[Int], String)]
```

I can't tell why the compiler thinks it should be `NotInferedR`; I can't find any documentation around this, and multiple tutorials that seem to think this is sufficient.

This is my `package.scala` file:

```
package nford

import slick.basic.DatabaseConfig
import slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile

package object domain {
  trait DatabaseBacking {
    val config: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]
    val db: JdbcProfile#Backend#Database = config.db
  }
}
```

This is my `User.scala` file:

```
package nford.domain

import nford.domain
import slick.basic.DatabaseConfig
import slick.dbio.DBIOAction
import slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile
import slick.lifted.{Index, MappedProjection}

import scala.concurrent.Future

case class User(id: Option[Int], name: Option[String])

trait UserTable {
  this: DatabaseBacking =>

  import config.profile.api._

  private class User(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "user") {
    def id: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def name: Rep[String] = column[String]("name")

    def * : MappedProjection[Nothing, (Option[Int], String)] = (id.?, name) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
  }

  val user = TableQuery[User]
}
```

How do I resolve this mismatch?

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but I just ran into the same issue and found this unanswered post. Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out *why* it's not working. I've seen examples write it as you have done, but maybe those examples are using a Scala version older than 2.12? Anyway, I found that using `mapTo` works for me. So, in your case it would be:

`def * : ProvenShape[User] = (id.?, name.?).mapTo[User]`

(I think name also needs `.?` since `name` is an `Option[String]` in the User class, and the `name` column is defined as a `String`)